# Why would Magento look in base skin folder instead of current skin folder?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript, local.xml

In my **local.xml** I have added a new javascript load command. It is exactly the same as another javascript.

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type
    <name>rateyo/jquery.rateyo.min.js</name>
</action>
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>jquery.cbpContentSlider.js</name>
</action>
```

Yet I get a 404 in the browser because the link created for the second is in base, not in my theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/rateyo/jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../skin/frontend/base/default/jquery.cbpContentSlider.js"></script>
```

WHY????????

I flush every cache, don't have compilation on, dont have merging, this is the dev site so no full page cache installed etc. etc. etc. Even though it sounds absurd I tried putting it in a subfolder, since that is one difference, but it has the same problem.

Why is one generated with correct skin reference and the other one not?

*updating with a few more details*

calling .../skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/js/jquery.cbpContentSlider.js in the browser works, which shows that file is in the wrong place. But the URL Magento generates, which has the js removed, does not work.

Comment: first magento search the files from theme folder, if not found then it uses the base folder content

Comment: Does your current theme have base as a parent?

Comment: rwd is the parent, which then has base as a parent.
but the file is in the correct location -  "https://.../skin/frontend/base/default/js/jquery.cbpContentSlider.js" exactly like there is a "https://.../skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/js/rateyo/jquery.rateyo.min.js"

But for one it generates the correct skin link, and the other one not, it reverts to base. Can it not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Magento looks in the base theme, this is generally because the file does not exist in your theme.

You should double check if the `jquery.cbpContentSlider.js` file is in `skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/` folder .

Comment: it has to be it - although the file is uploaded to the right place, something has to be preventing the php code from seeing it. Permissions seem right, so I will need to figure out if there's stupid rewrites or security settings somewhere on the host that block it.

Comment: the files are both under skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/js/ - and for one the link put in the html (without /js/) skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/ works and for the other one it doesn't. Puzzling

Comment: If your files are in `skin/frontend/rwd/alpine2/js/`, you should write :
    
    <action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type
    <name>js/rateyo/jquery.rateyo.min.js</name>
</action>
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/jquery.cbpContentSlider.js</name>
</action>

Comment: yikes. i thought because the other one worked that the js was more of magento's mystery autorewrites. The mystery now is not why one doesn't work, it's why the other does work. That is someone else's mess... I should have gotten the hint the first time i noticed the missing js, rather than imagine "magic"